# Intent.setClass in android

Tags: android, notifications

i'm developing android app where i create a notification programmatically like this :

```
 public void createNotification()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent().setClass(IncomingCallScreen.this,IncomingCallScreen.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(IncomingCallScreen.this, 0, intent,0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
                .setContentText("there is a call running")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.answer)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.reject, "HangUp", contentIntent)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

this function is called in onpause state what i want to do is when the activity in onpause and the user click on the notification the activity can be in front again like whatsapp when i accept a call and if i go back or press home a notification is presed to bring the call screen again.
but what happens is when i press on the notification the app is closed!

Note : the context is the same as the class i want to go to (may be this is the issue) also lunchMode:SinleTop is exist for this activity

Comment: Try the updated code I have posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing  from 0 to PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT at 
    `PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(IncomingCallScreen.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);` solved the problem

```
public void createNotification()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(IncomingCallScreen.this,IncomingCallScreen.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(IncomingCallScreen.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(IncomingCallScreen.this)
                .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
                .setContentText("there is a call running")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.answer)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.reject, "HangUp", contentIntent)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Second.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        // notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        //
        // notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
        // notification.ledOnMS = 300;
        // notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
        // notification.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        // notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();

        Log.e("screen on.................................", "" + isScreenOn);

        if (isScreenOn == false) 
        {

            WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                    | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                    | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyLock");

            wl.acquire(10000);
            WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    "MyCpuLock");

            wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
        }
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Comment: i tried the app is closed , the problem is Second.class is the same context the notification is created bacouse i create the notification in Activity A and i want when the user press it goes to activity A once again! when i change it to another activity it works but this is not what i want